# Why the user is getting "undefined" as value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

Here I am trying to verify the user using `jwt` token and then deletion of his account will be take place.

**File: user.route.js**

```js
import express from "express";
import { verifyToken } from "../utils/verifyUser.js";
import { deleteUser } from "../controllers/user.controller.js";
const router = express.Router();

router.delete("/delete/:userId", verifyToken, deleteUser);

export default router;
```

**File: verifyUser.js**

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { errorHandler } from "./error.js";

 export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
 console.log("Verifying process is called..");

 const token = req.cookies.access_token;

 console.log(`Token data: ${token}`);

 // console.log(`Your Token :${token}`);

  if (!token) {
   console.log("No Token found");
   return next(errorHandler(401, "Unauthorized"));
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
   if (err) {
   console.log("Token verification error");
   return next(errorHandler(401, "Unauthorized"));
  }
   console.log(`User data: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
   //user is added to the request
   req.user = user;
   // to invoke the second function in the put()
   next();
  });
};
```

**File: user.controller.js**

```js
import { errorHandler } from "../utils/error.js";
import User from "../models/user.model.js";
//Delete Account Function
export const deleteUser = async function(req, res, next) {
  //checking the user id
  if (req.user.id !== req.params.userId) {
    console.log(`User ID: ${req.user.id}`);
    console.log(`Params: ${req.params.userId}`);
    return next(errorHandler(403, "You're not allowed to delete this user"));
  }
  try {
    await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.userId);
    res.status(200).json("User account is deleted");
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

But while checking the user in the **verifyUser.js** is assigned with undefined value.

As the result, `req.user` gets undefined as value.

So, that the deletion is not working as expected.

Can anyone help me with a solution for this?

Comment: Could you show us the logs please ?

Comment: check the token if its payload has the required data